# Phython, my script can run but nothing happens

Tags: python, speech-recognition

so I´ve been working on my school project and making progress, and it looks like everthing works at this stage, but for some reason when I run the script nothing happens. I could try removing some lines of code and try to figure out the issue but I really dont know what to remove since I need everything on the code right now. If someone could help i really would appreciate.

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import subprocess as sp
import random
import datetime
import wikipedia
import pyjokes
import sys

Audio = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

#Inicio a libraria para fazer o script falar
def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def Commands():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
                print("Say something: ")
                voice = Audio.listen(source)
                Order = Audio.recognize_google(voice)
                Order = Order.lower() #Passa todo o que for dito para letras minusculas
        
                if 'ray' in Order:
                    Order = Order.replace('ray', '')
                    print(Order)
                    print("You said: " + Order)
    except: 
        pass
    return Order

def ray_commands():

    order=Commands()
    print(order)
    #Caso o utilizador queira abrir algum aplicativo o programa vai reconhecer a palavra chave
    #É capaz de abrir: Calculadora, Notepad, write e paint
    if "open" in order: 
        if "calculator" in order:
            sp.Popen('C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe')
        if "Notepad" in order:
            sp.Popen('C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe')
        if "wordpad" in order:
            sp.Popen('C:\\Windows\\System32\\write.exe')
        if "paint" in order:
            sp.Popen('C:\\Windows\\system32\mspaint.exe')
                    #Algumas "dad jokes" caso o utilizador esteja numa para se rir
    if "tell me a joke" in order:
        print(pyjokes.get_joke())

        if "tell me the time" in order:
            time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
                    
                    #A palavra chave para fechar o script é close
        if "close" in order:
            print("Goodbye")
            sys.exit()
```

Please ignore the comments troughout the code, im portuguese haha

Comment: You don't call your functions in somewhere.  You must call them for running them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is only declaring functions, not running them.

You have to actually call on each function to make it run.

Add this to the bottom of the script to run each of the functions in order-

```
talk("yourtext")
ray_commands()
```

I didn't list `Commands()` because `ray_commands()` already calls on this function.

Comment: Well this was extremely embaressing, thanks for pointing that out i spent some good 30minutes looking for some explations and it was something this simple haha, thanks for the help and sorry for the stupid post

Comment: No problem. If this solved your issue please accept the answer.